# UITableView cells in random order after using scrollToRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

So after I add this code below the comment:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    // HERE
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

My cells mess up (generated randomly) when scrolling. Before adding this code they behave as expected.

I think it has to do with the fact that cells are reused, and I don't know how to fix this.

Any explanations as to why?

cellForRowAt method for more detail:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
        cell.messageText.text = messages[indexPath.row].body
        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.email == messages[indexPath.row].sender{
            cell.isIncoming = false
        } else {
            cell.isIncoming = true
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cells are recycled. In your table view's data source, you need to dequeue a cell and fully configure it with data from your model.

If you allow your user to interact with your table view, you need to save those changes into your model so that if the cell scrolls off-screen, you recreate it correctly when it scrolls back on-screen.

You haven't provided enough information about how you set up your cells for us to provide more help than that.

If you want more specific help, edit your question to show your data source methods (in particular your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method.)